# Start text on second page (without \chapter) at same position as on first page (with \chapter)

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters

This MWE shows what I am trying:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}%
\chapter*{A}%
Some text%
\clearpage%
\vspace*{-1pt}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\chapter*{A}%
Some text without heading, starting at the same position as above.%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}%
```

I need the minipage in order to prevent page-breaking of its contents. I have two questions:

1. Why do I need -1pt before the minipage? Is there some minipage spacing I need to adapt? In a different document, I even need -9.75 (I am using \titleformat from the titlesec package there).
2. What can I do to hide \chapter*? I know \phantom, but this does not seem to work (does not compile). \textcolor{white} would work, but is not very nice when copying text from the pdf.

**Edit:** The answer to `1` is `\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}`. God knows why the default (when omitting `[t]`) looks like top alignment, but yields a different result. @Herbert's answer to `2` is perfect, I had tried `\phantom{\chapter*{A}}`. Thanks!

Comment: the default minipage is vertically centered so its height is much more than baseline spacing so `\lineskip` glue is inserted. With `[t]` the height is small so you get the normal baseline spacing,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{A}
Some text

\chapter*{\phantom{A}}
Some text without heading, starting at the same position as above.
\end{document}
```